# How to set the OpenFileDialog to open at 'My Computer'

Tags: .net, openfiledialog, special-folders

I wanted my `OpenFileDialog` to start at My Computer to show all available drives. You would assume you could set the `InitialDirectory` property to `GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)`, but this function returns "", which doesn't have the desired result.

Digging around on Google I found this solution - which works

```
dlg.InitialDirectory = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}"
```

Can anybody explain what this GUID actually is, and whether it will work across all versions of Windows? ie. How reliable is this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.insidetheregistry.com/regdatabase/browse.aspx?keyid=374

It says it was used in Windows NT4/2000. I have Windows 7, and this GUID is still used for My Computer.